# How can i get Vertical scrolling in GridView android?

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I am developing an android application with showing images. I am using `grid view` to show the images in my application.

But default gridview is `horizontal scrolling` I want to show the images in `vertical scrolling` grid view.

Please suggest me a way to achieve vertical scrolling in gridview.

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `android:numColumns="3" // this will force gridview to have 3 columns and if you have more than 3 items in grid view, you can have vertical scrolling.`

**Ex.:**

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i dont want horizontal scroll. what i mean if i have 12 images i want to show 4 in first view and next 4 in next another 4 in next. I want almost like gallery but with 4 image views

Comment: okay, so just instead of 3, use 4 as numOfCloumns..that would satisfy your requirement.. right?

Comment: Why are you using layouts if your problem can be solved by using GridView?

Comment: this doesn't work for me. i have 24 items. so its exceeds the screen size to fit. I am only displayed with 16 which will fit  in screen with no scrolling