# Listview 5 "items" horizontal with a vertical scroll Android

Tags: android, android-listview, vertical-scrolling

I would like to know how to make a `ListView` with 5 items per row horizontal with a vertical scroll

Comment: take a GridView with 5 column instead of Listview.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom row, then have 60 rows.

Lets asume you have an

```
ArrayList<String> cars
```

with the cars data.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {  
       //Determine the first car
       int firstCarPosition = position*5;
       CarListItem item = new CarListItem(context);
       item.fillItem(firstCarPosition);
       return item;
    }
```

then create a class like this one

```
public class CarListItem extends LinearLayout {

  public SingleRowListItem(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater =     (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_cars_row, this, true);
  }

 public void fillItem(int firstPosition)
 {
     TextView car1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.car1);
     TextView car2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.car2);
     TextView car3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.car3);
     TextView car4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.car4);
     TextView car5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.car5);

     car1.setText(cars.get(firstPosition);
     car2.setText(cars.get(firstPosition+1);
     car3.setText(cars.get(firstPosition+2);
     car4.setText(cars.get(firstPosition+3);
     car5.setText(cars.get(firstPosition+4);
 }
}
```

Finally, create an XML called list_item_car_row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/standard_background"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/car1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/car2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/car3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/car4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/car5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="wrap_content"/>  
</LinearLayout>
```

That is what is called a component, a not system default item. This component is based on 6 textviews. Edit the XML, add it more data and make a cool one :)

Answer (score 1):

As I got it, you want to make a ordinary `ListView` with vertical Scrolling but in every row you want to have Horizontal Scrolling too.

Make ordinary `ListView` with any adapter you like but design the item Layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hor_scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="6.0dip"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:focusable="false" />

            <TextView
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

You'll have Vertically `Scrollable ListView` with horizontally scrollabel items.

Comment: @jilbera. How will then one item will only be visible when the list item is not horizontally scrolled ?

Comment: Sorry @GauravArora, I couldn't understand your question.

Comment: I have 10 rows and some rows have more than one data which I have to show using horizontal scrolling, but only one data should be visible on scrolling.

Comment: Oh, that's a different problem, I think you should have ListView in an item row view which will be horizontaly scrollable but I don't know if it's possible . . .

Answer (score 0):

You must create a vertical ListView with a custom ListAdapter with the derired 5 items per row. You can describe the layout of the rows in a XML layout file. For example see http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-adapter-and.html .

Comment: I may not have explained well. I need, for example, from a list of 300 cars get there 5 cars per row, each with his description, name, color ... you understand?

Comment: GridView with vertical scrolling? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456711/how-can-i-get-vertical-scrolling-in-gridview-android

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a layoutfile with a Listview

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then in code you need an ArrayAdapter (I always create my own!) to populate your list and a item_layout for every item

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_layout, someArrayList);
        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter );
```

Comment: It's not what I want. My listview must have 5 "cars" per row and 300 rows with vertical scroll. I don't know how to do. Write XML and Adapter class if it is possible. Thanks a lot

Comment: Like this |Car1|Car2|Car3|Car4|Car5| and then 300 rows below it that looks like it??