# Interesting Android Layout - How is it done?

Tags: android, android-layout

I apologise if this sort of question is not allowed on SO.

I recently found this app with a really interesting/unusual layout. What really stands out is the way the grid can be swiped both vertically and horizontally, giving a comparable effect to a Rubicks Cube.

I'm not looking at implementing this anywhere, so I'm not looking for coded examples; I am just curious as to how the developer has achieved this interface? At first glance, it does look like a simple `Gridview` as suggested below, but as far as I understand a `Gridview` cannot be scrolled both vertically and horizontally on each row and column. This interaction is quite difficult to explain, the app is [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.bbc.cbbcgocbbc&hl=en_GB) on the play store, with a short snippet of a video showing the interaction. I'd imagine that it is unavailable for install outside of the UK unfortunately.

[image]

Comment: @Krupal a simple gridview does not scroll single column wise or row wise

Comment: Can this be taken off hold? Does it violate the rules, is it actually that broad? I don't know how I could narrow the question down any more. It is an interesting layout, it is unlikely that there are that many ways of achieving it that would render it 'too broad'. Also, is the edit that was made not a little pedantic?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a simple `GridView`. Here is the developer documentation and API Guide on `GridView`:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

I have also included a tutorial on implementing a custom `GridView` with both images and text, similar to what is shown in your question:

http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html

**EDIT**

I just saw the part in your question regarding scrolling. You can setup `GridView` to do scrolling. Here is an SO post regarding the matter:

[How can i get Vertical scrolling in GridView android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456711/how-can-i-get-vertical-scrolling-in-gridview-android)

Comment: I am not sure a simple gridview is enough here, as if you can see by the video individual columns and rows can scroll independently. AFAIK gridview cannot do that

Comment: I missed that part of the question originally. See my updated answer